# Laravel Container Dependencies Auto-resolving

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, ioc-container

When is it necessary to explicitly register classes in a container?

Let's say I've got a class that depends on some standard Laravel's components:

```
<?php

class Dump
{
    public function __construct(
        \Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository $config,
        \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
    }
}
```

Normally I would do this in a service provider:

```
$this->app->singleton(Dump::class, function (Application $app) {
    return new Dump($app->make('config'), $app->make('files'));
});
```

However, I see that it's redundant. Laravel resolves and injects these components itself if I do `resolve(Dump::class)`. I just encountered this in an integration test.

What if there is another class depending on `Dump`? Would Laravel resolve `Dump` and inject it into the depending custom class? Could you explain what it can/can't resolve and inject automatically and where? Only the standard places like jobs/controllers or wherever? Seems like I'm missing something in the understanding of the container.

Comment: How do you get `Dump` instance in problem code?

Comment: @maximkou Injected via the constructor of a Command. But I might want to get it injected into the constructor of another custom ("non-laravel") class

Comment: Please read first paragraph of https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#automatic-injection

Comment: Shortly, it only works with system classes. In other cases you must inject service manually, using, to example, `resolve` function.